# How to check for the existence of a value in a column within a Select CASE expression

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I want to get all of the people in a database by name, and have a `BIT` field to denote whether or not at least one of their jobs is as a plumber. If I have a query like this:

```
SELECT p.Name,
       CASE
           WHEN EXISTS (select 1 FROM j WHERE j.Name = 'plumber') THEN 1
           ELSE 0
           END IsPlumber
FROM People p INNER JOIN Jobs j
     ON j.personId = p.Id
GROUP BY p.Name
```

It seems to make sense, but doesn't work because I get `Invalid object name 'j'`. I can do a count like this:

```
...
    COUNT(
        CASE
            WHEN j.Name = 'plumber' THEN 1
            END) > 0
            THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END IsPlumber
...
```

But `COUNT` is less efficient as far as I'm aware, and I just feel like I should be able to go with the top variant somehow. How do I make that work?

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*.

Comment: So if someone is a plumber and an astronaut, you want two rows output, and both rows say `IsPlumber = 1`? That's what an `INNER JOIN` will do.

Comment: If somebody is a plumber and an astronaut, I want one row where `IsPlumber = 1`, hence the `GROUP BY`

Comment: Ok. You should further clarify whether you want a person returned if they have _no_ rows in jobs (plumber or otherwise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a join to accomplish this you need to use a `LEFT JOIN` and the aggregate function, `MAX`, to calculate it.

```
SELECT p.Name
    , MAX(CASE
        WHEN j.Name = 'plumber' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END) IsPlumber
FROM People p
LEFT JOIN Jobs j ON j.personId = p.Id
GROUP BY p.Name
```

Alternatively you could put the complete exists query in the `CASE` expression.

```
SELECT p.Name
    , CASE
        WHEN EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM Job j
            WHERE j.PersonId = p.Id
            AND j.Name = 'plumber'
        ) THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END IsPlumber
FROM People p
GROUP BY p.Id, p.Name
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to show if "at least on of the jobs is plumber". This query will show that for each job separately.

Comment: I suppose my thinking went off the rails when I forgot that I'll _have_ to use an aggregate function with group by. Thanks for the clarity.

Comment: Just wanted [to be inclusive](https://dbfiddle.uk/7hMuPi40). :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand That's a fantastic bit of work there; thank you so much for that!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the same person can't have the same job name twice, a join without any aggregation is also possible.

```
SELECT p.Name, 
  IsPlumber = CASE WHEN j.Name IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM dbo.People AS p
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Jobs AS j
  ON p.Id = j.personId
  AND j.name = 'plumber';
```

Another way is to use `OUTER APPLY`:

```
SELECT p.Name, IsPlumber = COALESCE(q.here, 0)
FROM dbo.People AS p
OUTER APPLY
(
  SELECT TOP (1) here = 1 
    FROM dbo.Jobs AS j
    WHERE j.Name = 'plumber'
      AND j.personId = p.Id
) AS q;
```

Of course both of the above will include people who have no job at all, which is why I asked for further clarification. If you only want people *with jobs*, you can use `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT p.Name, IsPlumber = CASE q.name 
       WHEN 'plumber' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM dbo.People AS p
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT TOP (1) j.name
    FROM dbo.Jobs AS j
    WHERE j.personId = p.Id
  ORDER BY CASE j.name WHEN 'plumber' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
) AS q;
```

[Working examples in this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/aBx8rH40).

These aren't necessarily better or worse than other solutions, they just avoid explicit aggregation.